# Can't work with Location object in FSL

Tags: apex, field-service-lightning

With Field Service Lightning, a `Location` object was added. When we try to work with this object it's always saying that we are referencing the `System.Location` object. How can I reference the `Location` object from FSL in Apex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to explicitly reference the field service Location object as Schema.Location since just saying Location implicitly refers to the older System.Location class.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was stumped on the same thing and was just about to post a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You can access FSL Location by using Schema.Location. This worked for me:

```
for(Schema.Location loc : [SELECT Id,Name FROM Location]) {
    System.debug(loc.Name);     
}
```